# How to update from json a Mongoengine DynamicDocument

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am trying to find an **elegant** way of updating an existing MongoDB document with the data received from a web page as json. The problem is that I do not know in advance which fields are going to be updated - so I can't use **set__field**, I only have a json representation of the fields to be updated in my MongoDB document. Plus I am using DynamicDocuments, so there might be new fields to be set on the document.
e.g.:

```
class Study(DynamicDocument):
    study_accession_nr = StringField()
    study_name = StringField()
    study_type = StringField()
```

and the json may look like - for example:

```
{"_id" : "123", "study_name" : "Statistics"}
```

or

```
{"_id" : "123", "study_type" : "research", "study_name" : "Statistical analysis"}
```

I can do it easily from the console, or using pymongo, but I don't know how to do this using Mongoengine, unless I manually setattr(myDocInstance, nameOfField, val), which does not look so elegant to me.
Thanks!

Comment: If you need pure schemaless DB, why you choose ORM with strict rules? You should try pymongo.

Comment: Because I want to have a hierarchy of documents and embedded documents, and to define a set of required fields, while I am quite flexible on the optional fields.

Comment: "hierarchy of documents and embedded documents" is you task as developer not ORM,  "and to define a set of required fields" if we talk about web app you can just validate forms from users.

Comment: It is not just a web app, it is the back end of a complex app that exposes in the front-end a REST API. And yes, I can define in the application's logic the hierarchy of documents, but then I would also have to rewrite some of the functionality implemented by an ORM (Mongoengine)

Comment: OK, I worked some time with Mongoengine and it's not ready for production. If you can then do away in order to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: I see...Well, then thank you for the advice. I am starting to get slightly annoyed with Mongoengine because I can't find good and complete examples of how to perform the operations mentioned in the documentation, and how should each parameter look like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just pass the data when you initiate the class:

```
data = {"_id" : "123", "study_type" : "research", "study_name" : "Statistical analysis"}
doc = Study(**data)
```

To update existing models you can either call update (preferred) or change the model and call save.

eg:

```
Doc.update(set__VAR=Val, set__VAR2=Val2)
```

Or

```
setattr(Doc, 'VAR', val)
setattr(Doc, 'VAR2', val2)
Doc.save()
```

or

```
Doc.VAR = val
Doc.VAR2 = val2
Doc.save()
```

Comment: Yes, but what I need is to modify an **existing** document, that has been initiated already in the past.

Comment: You need to set the attributes either on the model or by issuing an update query.

Comment: Ok. And if I set the attributes on the model - and assume that they are fixed, how does the update query look like, in case I don't know in advance which fields I want to update, and I just get them as json?

Comment: Updated the example - the last two are effectively the same - but you might want to abstract it by adding a method to update based on a dict

Comment: Ok, these are roughly the solutions that I was thinking of too. I thought there might be another way of doing this, using the update function from Mongoengine, but I couldn't make it work. Thanks!

Comment: I have just noticed that an update done the way you suggested - using setattr - is not atomic...

Comment: How does that impact you?  The actual database update will be with the save.

Comment: It impacts me a lot because what I do is: first retrieve the doc from the DB, then update some fields from that doc **depending on**  the value of other fields of the doc I have just retrieved...which sounds a bit like I should put everything in a transaction...

Comment: If you have to bring the data back from the server and change it in python, then yes there is a race condition.  So you could use an optimistic locking pattern or an atomic $set or $findAndModify query.

Answer (score 1):

Normal MongoEngine. In my case I receive a form from x-editable that has the fields with the same name as my schema so I can go direct to the database with this.

```
ActivityType.objects.filter(id=request.form['pk']).update(**{'set__'+request.form['name']: request.form['value']})
```